# Fazer página carregar apenas quando clico no botão

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu estou criando um mini game, só que eu quero que o jogo inicia somente quando clicar no botão ou apertar alguma tecla do teclado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você poderia "iniciar um jogo" a partir de um evento de clique em um botão.
Separando o seu código por funções no javascript, poderá utilizar o [onClick()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Jogo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="iniciarJogo()">Iniciar</button>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    function iniciarJogo() {
        //código do jogo
        console.log("iniciar")
    }
</script>
```

Para realizar o inicio ao pressionar alguma tecla no teclado você poderia utilizar o mesmo conceito, mas utilizando [onKeyDown](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event) no HTML, lendo o body com [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) e adicionando o evento com [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), dessa forma:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Jogo</title>
</head>
<body onkeydown="teclaPressionada()">
    <button onclick="iniciarJogo()">Iniciar</button>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    function teclaPressionada() {
        document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
            iniciarJogo()
        });
    }

    function iniciarJogo() {
        //código do jogo
        console.log("iniciar")
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo aqui, juntei seu código com o do brother ai em baixo e ficou top <3

Answer (score -2):

Olá !

Partilho um exemplo que deixei no codesandbox com o qual pode iniciar o jogo ao clique e desligar os conteúdos diretamente da página do HTML:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <!-- Página inicial -->
    <div class="div_body" id="intro">
      <h1>
        Jogo
      </h1>
      <div class="buttons_start">
        <button id="comecarJogo">Começar Jogo</button>
        <a href="./comojogar.html"><button>Como jogar</button></a>
        <button>Ajuda</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Página do jogo -->
    <div class="div_body" id="ambiente_jogo">
      <h1>
        Começar
      </h1>

      <div id="conteudos_jogo">
        <div id="background_game"></div>
        <div id="elemento1"></div>
        <div id="elemento2"></div>
        <div id="elemento4"></div>
        <div id="elemento5"></div>
        <div id="elemento3"></div>
      </div>
      <button id="back_btn">Voltar</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
#ambiente_jogo {
    display: none;
  }

  #intro {
    display: block;
  }
```

Script.js:

```
   document.getElementById("comecarJogo").onclick = function () {
  //começar jogo
  document.getElementById("intro").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ambiente_jogo").style.display = "block";
};

document.getElementById("back_btn").onclick = function () {
  //regressar ao menu jogo
  document.getElementById("intro").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("ambiente_jogo").style.display = "none";
};
```

Ou pode utilizar um link à volta do seu botão que irá abrir uma página nova de HTML (terá que criar um novo ficheiro HTML):

```
<div class="div_body" id="intro">
      <h1>
        Jogo
      </h1>
      <div class="buttons_start">
        <button id="comecarJogo">Começar Jogo</button>
        <a href="./comojogar.html"><button>Como jogar</button></a>
        <button>Ajuda</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-shamir-w672s6?file=/index.html:3136-3446

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo aqui, juntei seu código com o do brother ai de cima e ficou top <3

Comment: Ainda bem que conseguiu!